# laravel - retrieving rss

Tags: php, laravel, rss

I try to retrieve rss from another site. I use this willvincent package for that. When I try to retrieve it I have error `illegal string offset title`

Controller:

```
$feed = Feeds::make('http://awiacja.imgw.pl/rss/metar00.php?airport=EPWA');
        $data = array(
      'title'     => $feed->get_title(),
      'permalink' => $feed->get_permalink(),
      'items'     => $feed->get_items(),
    );
        return view('home',['data' => $data]);
```

View:

```
  @foreach($data as $datum)
  <li>{{$datum['title']}}</li>
  @endforeach
```

I want to retrive only info from this link :http://awiacja.imgw.pl/rss/metar00.php?airport=EPWA

Comment: `return var_dump($data);` in your controller. So you can debug $data passed to the view.

Comment: but it dump all data and i want to dump only description

Comment: I just ran into this issue.have you solved this